# Chrome stable and Chrome Canary use a different color profile (Mac OSX)

Tags: google-chrome, colors, monitors, color-profile

Below is a screenshot of the same hex code. Right is Canary and left is the stable version of Chrome. Canary uses a wrong color profile (I think), the bright version is the "wrong" one. Does anybody know how I can figure out where the problem is and how I can solve it?

I know colors will always look different on different monitors, but it's strange it's happening on my laptop screen with two different browsers. Also, there are things that can trigger the stable version into working with the wrong color profile. For example:

- Embedding an iframe
- -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

I've found out that these two cause Chrome stable into changing the colors (I presume it's because it uses a different color profile). The result is a see a quick change of all my colors on page load. I've tested it with backface-visibility, inspect the element and tick that css property on/off and I definitely see a change of the colors.

Here is the difference:

[image]

I'm using a MacBook Pro
OSX 10.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered with this problem today

1. Go to `chrome://flags/`
2. Search for 'color' and switch `Force color profile` flag to different. In my case - sRGB